# How may the epigraph be justified?

Tags: justification, epigraphs

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.82\textwidth}

\epigraph{\emph{«Nur wenn man nicht auf den Nutzen nach aussen sieht, sondern in der Mathematik selbst auf das Verhältnis der unbenutzten Teile, bemerkt man das andere und eigentliche Gesicht dieser Wissenschaft. Es  ist nicht zweckbedacht, sondern unökonomisch und leidenschaftlich.  [\ldots]
Die Mathematik ist Tapferkeitsluxus der reinen Ratio, einer der wenigen die es heute gibt.»}}
{Robert Musil, \emph{Der mathematische Mensch}, %\texttt{
Mitteilungen der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung, Noº20, page 50, 1912.}

The introduction comes here \ldots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `\justifying` macro from the `ragged2e` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.82\textwidth}

\epigraph{\justifying\emph{«Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, ma- gna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.»}}
{Author}

The introduction comes here \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need extra packages. The `epigraph` package already provides the method.

Comment: @egreg Oh, what a clever package! Good to know!

Answer (score 3):

Set `\textflush` to `flushepinormal` (manual, page 3).

I suggest `\dots\unkern` in order to remove an awkward space and upright shape for the brackets.

But if you want justification, you ***must*** load the appropriate language.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.82\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\epigraph{\begin{otherlanguage*}{ngerman}\em «Nur wenn man nicht auf den Nutzen nach aussen sieht, 
  sondern in der Mathematik selbst auf das Verhältnis der unbenutzten 
  Teile, bemerkt man das andere und eigentliche Gesicht dieser 
  Wissenschaft. Es  ist nicht zweckbedacht, sondern unökonomisch und 
  leidenschaftlich.~\textup{[\dots\unkern]}
  Die Mathematik ist Tapferkeitsluxus der reinen Ratio, einer der 
  wenigen die es heute gibt.»\end{otherlanguage*}}
{Robert Musil, \emph{Der mathematische Mensch},
  Mitteilungen der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung, Noº20, page 50, 1912.}

The introduction comes here \dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare the (wrong) hyphenation you get without `babel`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.82\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\epigraph{\em «Nur wenn man nicht auf den Nutzen nach aussen sieht, 
  sondern in der Mathematik selbst auf das Verhältnis der unbenutzten 
  Teile, bemerkt man das andere und eigentliche Gesicht dieser 
  Wissenschaft. Es  ist nicht zweckbedacht, sondern unökonomisch und 
  leidenschaftlich.~\textup{[\dots\unkern]}
  Die Mathematik ist Tapferkeitsluxus der reinen Ratio, einer der 
  wenigen die es heute gibt.»}
{Robert Musil, \emph{Der mathematische Mensch},
  Mitteilungen der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung, Noº20, page 50, 1912.}

The introduction comes here \dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend `babel`